# PowerApps Launch Phone dialer

Tags: powerapp, applauncher

I'm creating a simple "Employee Contacts" app which pulls our active employees from a Contact list. This is is searchable by last name and returns the name, photo, job title and shift like this:

[image: Screen1]

Once you click on the entry you want, you will see additional details on a second screen like this:

[image: Screen2]

We want to be able to click on the Cell phone field and bring up the phone's dialer and populate the phone number accordingly.

I am using this code in the Cell phone data field:

```
Launch("tel://ThisItem.'Mobile Phone'")
```

But it brings up the dialer with a wildly different number. In my example, a 10 digit phone number (with no dashes or parens) comes back on the dialer as "8447483666245374663" -- obviously not the correct phone number.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? I'm using Android in this example, but I need it to to work on the iPhone as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

gpence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a work-around of sorts. I added an icon for the Phone and Email and then added the OnSelect code to the icon which did allow the process to work.

[image: Icon Solution]

The code for the phone dialer (in the OnSelect) is:

```
Launch("tel:"&SelectedEmp.'Mobile Number')
```

With similar code for the email with "Mailto:" instead of "tel:' (plus the email field, obviously).

I'm not sure why it wouldn't work without using the icon.

gpence

Comment: At least you have shared an alternative. Accept your answer please.